# Vectorized way to copy elements from pandas Series to python built-in array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, vectorization, series

Is there a vectorized way to copy elements from a pandas Series to a python built-in array? For example:

```py
from array import array
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(range(0, 10, 2)); s += 0.1
a = array('d', [0.0]*10)

# I am looking for a vectorized equivalent of the below line:
for n,x in enumerate(s): a[n] = x
```

In my case, the array is given as a memory buffer to an external code, which saves the array address and only re-reads array values upon each call. So, I cannot recreate the array and need to only replace its values as quickly as possible.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from array import array
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(range(0, 10, 2)); s += 0.1
a = array('d', [0]*10)
    
temp = array('d',s) 
a[:len(temp)] = temp
```

Comment: You are creating a new array from the series instead of copying the values. This is exactly what I cannot do, as it is explained in my question.

Comment: You creating a new array in your code as well, after creating the new array you are assigning the values of `s` to `a`. I wrote the answer above according to this comment in your code `# I am looking for a vectorized equivalent of the below line:`.

Comment: I'll update my answer.

Comment: I am not creating a new array: the array is created in the beginning of the code and can never change. The code processes multiple Series objects that need to be copied into **the same** array.

Comment: How can I copy the `numpy` view into the array?

Comment: You can define your array `a` to be a numpy array. then you can use `numpy.add()` to add the new array to it, without copying or creating a new array.

Comment: No, the array cannot be defined as a `numpy` array: the external code expects a built-in array as input.

Comment: Can't you create the built-in array after using the code above and convert resulted numpy array to builtin-in array?

Comment: No, I cannot. The code structure is the following: pass a built-in array to the external C++ code (which will save the array address), then loop over multiple series objects. One loop iteration: copy a series into the array and call the external code which will process the array content.

Comment: This can be done using a temporary array to keep the Series in it. I'll update the code

Comment: "Update 3" satisfices the requirements.

Comment: If you find it useful, mark it as answer.

Comment: It is definitely useful. Thank you! I voted your answer up. If nobody comes up with an even better answer, I will accept it.